# Unable to delist from SORBS blacklist

Tags: ip, blacklist

The IP address of one of my servers has been blacklisted by [SORBS](http://www.sorbs.net).  The delisting process on their website does not work correctly for me.

Asides from contacting SORBS directly, is there anything else I can do to get my server removed from the blacklist?

Comment: The kind folks of Server Fault are here to answer questions to help you! Not do your Job for you! - For future reference most if not all blacklists will provide you with instructions for removal. SORBS is one of these.

Comment: I think the problem is sorbs.net doesn't work properly. The website itself works but when you try to delist your ip it needs au.sorbs.net to work too.. and that is giving: `The server at www.au.sorbs.net is taking too long to respond.` so the OP can't do anything actually. Besides he's not asking you to do it, but how to do it, and i guess this is because sorbs.net doesn't work properly.

Comment: I appreciate from reading through the posts below, that the website is not working correctly(I have even tried myself). If you read the question it looks as if the OP has not even attempted to resolve his own issue. I propose a edit of the question.

Comment: Perhaps: My mailservers IP Address 70.38.31.110 has been blacklisted by SORBS. I have attempted to delist using the website however it appears to be down! Would anyone know if there is another way to request a delisting of my IP Address?

Comment: He may have formulated question wrong, but the problem is valid. I assume he knew about the website since by checking it myself I was able to verify the problem. He just didn't give an overview of what he tried and what may be the bigger picture. On the other hand he could be young admin who just saw his server being blacklisted and in panic posted here as he didn't know where else to look for help. Down voting him doesn't help him or anyone else looking for an answer to problems like that.

Comment: It isn't our place to support failings of the SORBS website.  If it isn't working, it does at least provide contact details.  Now a good question would be if SORBS is not able to process delisting properly, what else is broken, and how valuable is their blacklist?

Comment: Ok - I hope Ryan doesn't mind me editing the question as I have done.  Hopefully this will solicit answers that will be more useful to the community at large.  Ryan, if I have trod on your feet, accept my apologies and comment here.

Comment: I've now upvoted the question as it now makes sense. The community can now benefit from this question and the answers. +1 to dunxd

Answer (score 4):

[SORB provide this information on their website](http://www.sorbs.net/overview.shtml).  I'm surprised you didn't look there first, so perhaps you meant to ask something a bit less obvious?

Comment: He can't do it this way. Sorbs website doesn't work as it should. Doesn't load some stuff from au.sorbs.net.

Comment: Engaging with SORBS is going to be necessary at some point whether their site works or not.

Answer (score 0):

Go to [MxToolBox](http://www.mxtoolbox.com/) and verify if SORBS is the only one listing you. It should give you overview of many spam engines. You can then go thru each of them and simply unlist yourself. Sometimes it's matter of time when they do it automatically, but sometimes you have to register yourself with proper email and do some confirmations.

Comment: i've checked it is only sorbes which has blacklisted our ip and their site is not working properly is their any other way to get it done

Comment: You are correct that au.sorbs.net seems to be not responding properly so reporting/delisting is a bit of pain. I guess the only thing you can do is wait for their website to start working.